# OnChange doesn't work javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I can't find my error. I looked at the other topics but no luck.

```
<div>
    <input id="date1" name="date1" type="date"> 
    <input id="date2" name="date2" type="date" onchange="date()">   
    <input id="date_diference" name="date_diference" type="date">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function date(){
        document.alert("hope to work");
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Working fine!!!http://jsfiddle.net/F7mhw/

Comment: it might be an issue if you browser doesn't support the html5 control..

Comment: which browser do u use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this won't work:

```
document.alert("hope to work");
```

this will

```
alert("hope to work");
```